# Display echo message when only two users are mutual connected

Tags: php

In my website users are mutual connected each other when the user A is connected to user B and vice versa. 
What I want to do in my system is to display a message to the logged in user that he has N number of unread message from a specific user.
I managed to do it only for one of the mutual connected user and display the appropriate message as we can see below .
[image]

What I want to do is to have multiplied messages for each mutual connected users.

My code to echo this message is the below ...

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(status) FROM messages WHERE status='0' AND recip='$username' AND auth='$friend'");       
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$messagesStatus = $row[0];  
$message= " <b><font color=red><p align='center'>You Have " . $messagesStatus . " Unread Messages From ".$friend."</font></b>";
$link_address = "members2.php?view=$friend"
?>
<a href="<?php echo $link_address;?>"> <?php echo $message; ?> </a>
```

And the code to check that if your a mutual connection with another user is this...

```
$mutual    = array_intersect($followers, $following);
$followers = array_diff($followers, $mutual);
$following = array_diff($following, $mutual);
$friends   = FALSE;
```

**Can you help me please to echo this message for each of my mutual connected users ? Thank you :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, mysql_query is an obsolete function (see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php) and I invite you to look to pdo (which I find easier to use too).

Turning back to your question, the first idea that comes to mind to me would be to forget about the `$friend` parameter in your SQL query and replace it by a `GROUP BY auth` .

This will give you an array grouping the number of messages from each author.

In the end, my query for your problem would be :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(status) as msg, auth FROM messages WHERE status='0' AND recip='$username' GROUP BY auth");
```

You should then use mysql_fetch_array to go through the result of your query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $message= " <b><font color=red><p align='center'>You Have " . $row['msg'] . " Unread Messages From ".$row['auth']."</font></b>";
    $link_address = "members2.php?view=".$row['auth'] 
}
```

Look at the examples given in the PHP doc of the functions for inspiration also. It helps.

Comment: These are the errors that I get http://prntscr.com/6pgtpw ,and this is how i write your code http://prntscr.com/6pgu05

Comment: Hum yes, I used mysql_fetch_array wrong. Here is the doc of the function : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Change the request to : `"SELECT COUNT(status) as msg, auth as author FROM messages WHERE status='0' AND recip='$username' GROUP BY auth"`

And the while function to : 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
    {
        $message= " <b><font color=red><p align='center'>You Have " . $row[ 'msg']. " Unread Messages From ".$row['author']."</font></b>";
        $link_address = "members2.php?view=$row['author']"
    }

It should work better (inspired from the doc)

Comment: ok thank you for the article, but still cant find what should i change

Comment: Comments are hard to change things. I will update my answer with a normally more suitable code.

Comment: First of all thank you for your time , new error in this line of code http://prntscr.com/6ph2et which says http://prntscr.com/6ph2qc

Comment: Try and concatenate your variable outside the string perhaps :
`"members2.php?view=".$row['auth']`